# Recording microphone with parec on Linux - noise

Tags: audio, debian, microphone, pulseaudio

I'm recording my microphone on Debian bullseye with following command:

```
parec -d 0 --file-format=wav example.wav
```

It works, but I have a static noise all the time in the recorded file. It's not very loud, I can hear everything I say to the mike, but it's annoying.

If I'm on say Teams meeting in browser with the same mike there's obviously no noise. So why is `parec` recording this way?